# How to install php-xml on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, xml, ubuntu

I have `php7.0` installed on Ubuntu 16.04 and I'm trying to install a forum software in apache2, but I get the following error:

> In order to function correctly, the PHP XML/DOM extension needs to be available.

I tried to execute

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

but these give me the following error:

> php-xml: Depends: php7.1-xml but it is not going to be installed

When I try to install `php7.1` from a PPA, I still get issues of dependencies from other PHP modules.

Any ideas how I can get `php-xml` installed without any dependency issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try installing the `.deb` files manually from here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+package/php-xml

Comment: thanx for your reply. I tried that,, but still i have to run "sudo apt-get install -f", which i  am not sure if is going to update something it shouldn;t. Is it safe?